# What's the "@"mark at the file description? 

Tags: command-line, permission, binary

I installed [princexml](http://www.princexml.com/download/) for Mac. With `ls -alF`, I have `-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 prosseek  admin  14190120 Jun  8 16:11 prince*`. What's the meaning of `@` in `-rwxr-xr-x@`?

And when I tried to execute the binary, I got `./prince: Operation not permitted` error message. Does this have anything with `@`?

Comment: The error message is unrelated to the @. But I don't have a guess on why it does occur. Did you untar/unzip the prince-macosx.tar.gz in Terminal or via double click in Finder?

Comment: @patrix: I did click in Finder (PathFinder to be precise) to open the tar file, after untag it in command line, everything works fine.

Comment: In Super User: [what does the @ mean on the output of ls on os x terminal?](http://superuser.com/q/155458/84988)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the file has [extended attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes). To see these attributes, run `xattr -l file`, to see the extended attributes of a particular file, or `ls -l@` to see the extended attributes of all files in a particular directory.

See the [man page for xattr](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html) as well.